# How to create columns from values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe like this:

```
             X1                   X2
1     Country                  Spain
2        Year                   2016
3       Value                  34.56
4     Country                  Italy
5        Year                   2016
6       Value                  48.21
7     Country                    USA
8        Year                   2016
9       Value                  84.37
10     Country                France
11       Year                   2016
12      Value                  18.94
```

etc.

X1 and X2 are columns. I scraped this data from a website, but I would like to have this:

```
Country    Year    Value
Spain      2016    34.56
Italy      2016    48.21
USA        2016    84.37
France     2016    18.94
```

I tried something with `gather()` function, but I failed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but I can't find a good post at the moment. The simplest method is `unstack(dat, X2~X1)`. where dat is the name of your data.frame. Note that the new columns are factors, so you have to go through them and convert the relevant ones to numeric. Something like `newDat[2:3] <- lapply(newDat[2:3], as.numeric)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your current dataframe is called `df` then this should do the trick:

```
Country <- df$X2[df$X1 == "Country"]
Value <- df$X2[df$X1 == "Value"]
Year <- df$X2[df$X1 == "Year"]

df_new <- data.frame(Country, Year, Value)
```

Comment: This help me a lot, thanks, but I have another problem. I have some missing data, not NA, but empty values, like have a Country: Syria, Year: 2016, and Value: nothing, it's empty. How can I make dataframe with this using your method?

Comment: I don't think dataframes can contain empty values (row numbers have to be the same across all columns). Maybe it's not empty but just a whitespace?

or is the data you're talking about not yet imported and you can't get it into a dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
output <- data.frame(t(matrix(data$X2,3)))
colnames(output) <- c("Country", "Year", "Value")
```

If you have variable lengths, but "Country" is always in the first row of a new "block of information" try:

```
library(data.table) # because i dont like data.frame
library(zoo) # for na.locf (last observation carried forward)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[X1 == "Country", X3 := 1:length(X1 == "Country")]
dt[, X3 := na.locf(X3)]
dt
dcast(dt, X3 ~ X1)
```

In essence this creates an ID column (X3) that you can use to dcast the table from a long into a wide format.

Comment: It's my mistake that I didn't mention that this data is messy. I have something like this in X1: Country, Year, Value, Country, Year, Value, Country, Value, Country, Year, Value, GDP, Country, Year, Value, ect.

Comment: Thought about that as well. If the data is complete (i.e. no missing values) and not mixed (i.e. the values for one country A follow after three other countries values, in this case it would clearly be impossible), you could try sorting the dataframe first by X1 and then do something similar to the above.

Comment: I adjusted my original answer to be more generic.